# Agora 4.2.0 with AR core

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, glsurfaceview, agora

I am trying to integrate AR core with Agora.
I am totally newbie to OpenGL concepts.

**what I have till now?**
I am using this sample [AR Kotlin](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_kotlin) in my application.

everything working fine with AR core
I have this class for sending custom video to Agora

```
    package com.ex.ab.arcore.kotlin.common.helpers

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context
import android.opengl.GLES30
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
import android.util.Log
import timber.log.Timber
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder


object GLSurfaceViewToI420Converter {
        private const val TAG = "GLSurfaceToI420"
        private const val BYTES_PER_PIXEL = Float.SIZE_BYTES // Assuming RGBA format
        private const val YUV_BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 3 // I420 format


    fun isAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val configurationInfo = activityManager.deviceConfigurationInfo
        return configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x30000
    }


    fun convertGLSurfaceViewToByteArray(width: Int, height: Int): ByteArray? {
        Timber.d("CHECK width = $width height = $height")
//        val width = glSurfaceView.width
//        val height = glSurfaceView.height
        val rgbaBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4)
        rgbaBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
        GLES30.glReadPixels(
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height,
            GLES30.GL_RGBA,
            GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            rgbaBuffer
        )

        // Convert to byte array
        val byteArray = ByteArray(rgbaBuffer.remaining())
        rgbaBuffer[byteArray]
        return byteArray
    }

    fun convertGLSurfaceViewToI420(width: Int, height: Int): ByteBuffer? {
        val framebuffer = IntArray(1)
        GLES30.glGenFramebuffers(1, framebuffer, 0)

        if (framebuffer[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CHECK Failed to generate framebuffer")
            return null
        }

        GLES30.glBindFramebuffer(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer[0])

        val texture = IntArray(1)
        GLES30.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0)

        if (texture[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CHECK  Failed to generate texture")
            GLES30.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, framebuffer, 0)
            return null
        }

        GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0])

        GLES30.glTexImage2D(
            GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
            GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null
        )

        GLES30.glFramebufferTexture2D(
            GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0], 0
        )

        if (GLES30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GLES30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CHECK Framebuffer is not complete")
            GLES30.glDeleteTextures(1, texture, 0)
            GLES30.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, framebuffer, 0)
            return null
        }

        val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * YUV_BYTES_PER_PIXEL)
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        val rgbaBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * BYTES_PER_PIXEL)
        rgbaBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

        GLES30.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgbaBuffer)

        convertRGBAToI420(rgbaBuffer, buffer, width, height)

        GLES30.glDeleteTextures(1, texture, 0)
        GLES30.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, framebuffer, 0)

        return buffer
    }

    private fun convertRGBAToI420(rgbaBuffer: ByteBuffer, i420Buffer: ByteBuffer, width: Int, height: Int) {
        val ySize = width * height
        val uvSize = ySize / 4

        for (i in 0 until height) {
            for (j in 0 until width) {
                val rgbaIndex = (i * width + j) * BYTES_PER_PIXEL
                val yIndex = i * width + j
                val uvIndex = ySize + (i / 2) * (width / 2) + (j / 2) * 2

                val r = rgbaBuffer.get(rgbaIndex).toInt() and 0xFF
                val g = rgbaBuffer.get(rgbaIndex + 1).toInt() and 0xFF
                val b = rgbaBuffer.get(rgbaIndex + 2).toInt() and 0xFF

                val y = ((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 128) shr 8) + 16
                val u = ((-38 * r - 74 * g + 112 * b + 128) shr 8) + 128
                val v = ((112 * r - 94 * g - 18 * b + 128) shr 8) + 128

                i420Buffer.put(yIndex, y.toByte())
                i420Buffer.put(uvIndex, u.toByte())
                i420Buffer.put(uvIndex + 1, v.toByte())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in OnDrawFrame() if I use `convertGLSurfaceViewToI420` this method it gives `Log.e(TAG, "CHECK Failed to generate framebuffer")` this error if I use `convertGLSurfaceViewToByteArray` this method I only see green screen on other end.

my code to send buffer looks something like

```
activity.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
      val width = activity.localSurfaceView.width
      val height = activity.localSurfaceView.height
//      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val isAvailable = GLSurfaceViewToI420Converter.isAvailable(activity.requireActivity())
      Timber.d("CHECK isavailable $isAvailable")
        val i420Buffer: ByteBuffer? =
          GLSurfaceViewToI420Converter.convertGLSurfaceViewToI420(width, height)
        i420Buffer?.let { data ->
      val byteArray = ByteArray(data.remaining())
      data.get(byteArray)
//      byteArray?.let {
        onByteArrayAvailable?.onByteDataAvailable(byteArray, width, height)
      } ?: kotlin.run {
        Timber.d("CHECK i420 is null")
      }
//      }
    }
```

I am not getting any error of exceptions. have also checked GLError.
If someone can point me to the solution it'll be great.

Comment: Not familiar with Agora but from https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=android there is a link to their github example project: https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/main/Android/APIExample which inside has some interesting functions to investigate like: https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/blob/main/Android/APIExample/app/src/main/java/io/agora/beautyapi/faceunity/FaceUnityBeautyAPIImpl.kt#L518